# What formats does Quick Look for iOS support for presenting 3D information?

Tags: ios, quicklook

I want to present some 3D models to my clients via email. I don't know what apps they have installed and I can't have then install any apps, most of them have a strict app policy.

What 3D formats does Preview for iOS support?

Comment: Preview for iOS? It doesn't exist as an app, though mail will preview some things. Empirically, .dae isn't one of them

Comment: You're right. I'm looking for something UIDocumentInteractionController can handle.

Comment: Guess I did not read the iOS part of the question... I will remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should look at what is listed here: [QLPreviewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/QLPreviewController)

Clipped from the developer site:

> A Quick Look preview controller can display previews for the following items:
>
> - iWork documents
> - Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)
> - Rich Text Format (RTF) documents
> - PDF files
> - Images
> - Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the
>   public.text type (see Uniform Type Identifiers Reference)
> - Comma-separated value (csv) files

As far as I know, the only format that could embed 3D information in the format is the PDF file. But does QLPreviewController render it? I do not know.

Maybe an alternative for you would be to make a WebGL website that you link your customers to?